# manipulating two 2D lists - python 2.7

Tags: python, list, 2d

if i have these two lists...

```
a = [[1,y,y],[2,x,x],[3,x,x],[4,y,y]
b = [[1,x,x],[4,x,x]
```

And i want to combine them such that a new list (c) is formed that contains each row of (a) if the first value of (a) is equal with the first value of (b)

```
c = [[1,y,y],[4,y,y]]
```

this is what i have tried so far...

```
for i in xrange(0,1):
    for j in xrange(0,3):
        if b[i][0] == a[j][0]:
           c[i:] = a[[j:]
```

overwriting values in the c array isnt a problem due to the type of data in (a).
Im just really stuck on this, any help on whether im on the right track or if i should try something else would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can consider using sets and list comprehensions.

```
a = [[1,'y','y'],[2,'x','x'],[3,'x','x'],[4,'y','y']]
b = [[1,'x','x'],[4,'x','x']]

b0s = set(l[0] for l in b)

c = [l for l in a if l[0] in b0s]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c.append(a[j])
```

inside your IF statement.

Comment: i couldn't get this one to work, although it did solve my flawed logic under the if statement! i found a nother solution but thx anyway